# Watermark rotation in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, watermark

I find the codeigniter image library is very useful, lot of features there. Only one point that I can't find, it is the watermark rotation. Anyone here ever done this using codeigniter image library?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library that comes with CI doesn't have a method for rotating the watermark. This is something you would have to add yourself or just create a rotated version of the image you are using to watermark your images and use that instead.